# Azure Active Directory Group and Group Members limit

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services, azureportal

What is the limit on the maximum groups that can be created in azure active directory and what is the maximum number of group members a group can contain?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal

Can't seem to find the limit in this documentation given by Microsoft

Comment: Hi, does my reply help? If so, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#active-directory-limits) for the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) service.

> - A non-admin user can create a maximum of 250 groups in an Azure AD organization. Any Azure AD admin who can manage groups in the
>   organization can also create unlimited number of groups (up to the
>   Azure AD object limit).
> - An Azure AD organization can have a maximum of 5000 dynamic groups.
> - A maximum of 100 users can be owners of a single group.

[image]